# How to simulate error frames and make error counters increase/decrease in CANoe using CAPL?

Tags: capl, canoe

I was trying to simulate two nodes in CANoe and made communication between them by sending messages to each other using a CAPL script.
When I think about generating error frames, I got to know about the CAPL function `output(errormessage)`.
How could we know whether it is active or passive error?
Whether it is Tx error or Rx error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The best solution is to use CANStress tool from Vector. This will allow you to create different errors (Bit field trigger, other trigger, analog disturbance). Basically you can define all the bits of a CAN frame.

[image]

you can find more description at: https://support.vector.com/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=a82c8ac81b321c548e9a535c2e4bcbcc&sysparm_viewer_table=kb_knowledge&sysparm_viewer_id=f2f482e41b2614148e9a535c2e4bcb6c

2. For types of error read: http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf